# Ms Access VBA Error 3070

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code in a form.

```
Dim rs As Object
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCustomer"
        Set rs = Forms!frmCustomer.Recordset.Clone
            rs.FindFirst "[CustomerID]=" & Me.CustomerID  <== Error Line
            Forms!frmCustomer.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmDebt", acSaveNo
```

If the user click a name the code open the `frmCustomer` and move to `CustomerID` based on `frmDebt`. Now I am getting an **Error 3070**.

The only change a made was on `frmCustomer`. I Added a `txtTotal` with:

```
ControlSource = DLookUp("[sumApp]-[sumFin]";"qtrDebt";
    "[CustomerID] = " & [CustomerID])
```

Any ideas please.

Comment: It looks like you're referring to the `ControlSource` property incorrectly - unless it's a variable. It might be helpful if you were to [edit] to add a few more lines around the part you changed.

Comment: Simple add a text box `txtTotal` with `Control Source Property = DLookUp("[sumApp]-[sumFin]";"qtrDebt"; "[CustomerID] = " & [CustomerID])`.

Comment: I made a small change `rs.FindFirst "[CustomerID]=" & Me.CustomerID` to this code `rs.FindFirst "[CustomerID]=" & CustomerID`. It is working, but can someone help me.

Comment: If it's working why do you need help?

Comment: Try using a ! Instead of a . After me. The exclamation point refers to a field, where the . refers to a control, and if your control and field are named the same, access can get confused.